# sklearn: use Pipeline in a RandomizedSearchCV?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'd like to be able to use pipelines in the RandomizedSearchCV construct in sklearn. However right now I believe that only estimators are supported. Here's an example of what I'd like to be able to do:

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.grid_search import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler    
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# get some data
iris = load_digits()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target

# specify parameters and distributions to sample from
param_dist = {'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 
          'gamma': [0.001, 0.0001], 
          'kernel': ['rbf', 'linear'],}

# create pipeline with a scaler 
steps = [('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('rbf_svm', SVC())]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

# do search
search = RandomizedSearchCV(pipeline, 
param_distributions=param_dist, n_iter=50)
search.fit(X, y)

print search.grid_scores_
```

If you just run like this, you'll get the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter kernel for estimator Pipeline
```

Is there a good way to do this in sklearn?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`RandomizedSearchCV`, as well as `GridSearchCV`, **do** support pipelines (in fact, they're independent of their implementation, and pipelines are designed to be equivalent to usual classifiers).

The key to the issue is pretty straightforward if you think, what parameters should search be done over. Since pipeline consists of many objects (several transformers + a classifier), one may want to find optimal parameters both for the classifier and transformers. Thus, you need to somehow distinguish where to get / set properties from / to.

So what you need to do is to say that you want to find a value for, say, not just some abstract `gamma` (which pipeline doesn't have at all), but `gamma` of pipeline's classifier, which is called in your case `rbf_svm` (that also justifies the need for names). This can be achieved using double underscore syntax, widely used in sklearn for nested models:

```
param_dist = {
          'rbf_svm__C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 
          'rbf_svm__gamma': [0.001, 0.0001], 
          'rbf_svm__kernel': ['rbf', 'linear'],
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think [this](https://medium.com/@dzenilee/randomized-or-grid-search-with-pipeline-cheatsheet-719c72eda68?source=friends_link&sk=c04ad319393084c2c7da23c5b5abcdf3) is what you need (section 3).

`pipeline.get_params().keys()` -> make sure your param grid keys match those returned by this.