# Pipeline & GridSearch not functioning together: error recognizing parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, gridsearchcv

If I use a pipeline like below, I receive the error message

```
Invalid parameter C for estimator Pipeline(steps=[('robustscaler', RobustScaler()), 
('svc', SVC())]). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`
```

```
pipe = make_pipeline(RobustScaler(), SVC())
param_grid = {'C':[1,2,3,4]}
grid = GridSearchCV(pipe,param_grid=param_grid , cv=5)
mod1 = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

On the contrary, the same param_grid outside the pipeline fits the model without error

```
param_grid = {'C':[1,2,3,4]}
grid = GridSearchCV(SVC(),param_grid=param_grid , cv=5)
mod1 = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

This happens with other estimators & scalers I have tried too, regardless of the parameter I would like to specify. Similarly, using the same pipeline, I can fit a model directly without GridSearchCV (`pipe.fit(X_train,y_train)`). However, the two cannot function together.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sklearn: use Pipeline in a RandomizedSearchCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178763/sklearn-use-pipeline-in-a-randomizedsearchcv)

Comment: yes, it is, thanks a lot!